# How to make initialized value with in @array in regrep compilation

Tags: perl

i try to run this code lines,

```
@checkpoint = split (/\s+/,$array_lcp[0]);
$i=scalar @checkpoint
print NAME " $checkpoint[0] ";
for ($k=0; $k<=i; $k++)
{
if ($array_ARGVTEMP[$d] =~ m/$checkpoint[$k]/i)
                    {
                            @array = split (/\s+/,$array_ARGVTEMP[$d]);
                            print NAME "   $checkpoint[$k]|  $k|| 
                            $checkpoint[0]|||  $checkpoint[1] ||||$checkpoint[2]|||||  ";
                    } }
```

but in the result warnings, it  said that:

"Use of uninitialized value within @checkpoint in regexp compilation at new3.pl line 64 (#2)" and line 64 is " if($array_ARGVTEMP[$d] =~ m/$checkpoint[$k]/i) "

Please help me, Thank you

Comment: That `$checkpoint[$k]` are elements of the array `@checkpoint` with indices `0, 1, 2` (what your `$k` is in the loop).  The "_uninitialized value within..._" means that the array `@checkpoint` doesn't actually have all those elements. So your first `split` probably returned not quite three elements, but fewer.  Print  out the whole `@checkpoint` to see.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**   The question changed. Originally the loop went to `$k<=2` (array size wasn't mentioned), what this answer addressed.  The main point remains and now it is clear that the loop goes up to the index *equal* to the array size, so one past the fence; the limit should be `$k < $i`. Thus "*value of `$k` for which there is no element*" mentioned below is the last one looped over.

---

The `$checkpoint[$k]`, that draws the warning in the regex, are elements of the array `@checkpoint` with indices `0, 1, 2` -- what `$k` is in the loop.

The "*uninitialized value within...*" means that the array `@checkpoint` doesn't actually have all those elements, so for a value of `$k` for which there is no element the regex attempts to retrieve an undefined value and complains.

The first `split` likely returned fewer than three elements. Print  out the `@checkpoint` to see.

A few more comments

- Please *always* have `use warnigs;` and `use strict;` at the beginning of a program
- Use *lexical filehandles*, so open files with `open my $name, ...` (not `open NAME, ...`)
- To loop over numbers from a range a nice way is

  ```
  for my $k (0..2) { ... }
  ```
- (**update**)   ... but the question changed, with the loop (intended to be) over all array elements and then there is no reason to use the index. Iterate directly over elements

  ```
  foreach my $checkpoint (@checkpoints) { .... }
  ```
- Whenever you use `\s+` for the separator pattern in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) most likely you should be using a special pattern `' '`, which splits by `\s+` and also disregards leading and trailing space.

Answer (score 2):

`@checkpoint` has `$i` elements numbered `0` to `$i-1`, but you're accessing the element at index `$i`.

```
for (my $k=0; $k<=$i; $k++)
```

should be

```
for (my $k=0; $k<$i; $k++)
```

Actually, it should be

```
for my $k (0..$#checkpoints)
```

Actually, it should be

```
for my $checkpoint (@checkpoints)
```